# Need to delete x number of characters from lists inside of list

Tags: python, list

My list looks like such:

```
lst = [['^160magenta'], ['S159magenta', '//159magenta'], ['R158black', 'S158black', 'T158black'], ['S157black', 'T157yellow'], ['//156yellow']]
```

I want it to look like:

```
lst = [['magenta'], ['magenta', 'magenta'], ['black', 'black', 'black'], ['black', 'yellow'], ['yellow']]
```

They are dynamic and may be different coords and colors.
I do have all the colors listed in the beginning from a selector so I could search for such in each list but idk if there is a much easier way.

Comment: Well `[[re.sub(r"[^a-z]", "", s) for s in x] for x in lst]` incidentally works on this list after making likely false assumptions about what a color might be, but what exactly defines these colors besides being in the list? If you have a set of colors, the lookups are O(1) and you'd need to do some splitting, but more specification seems needed here. For example, what if a string has `#fff`? That's a color... Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post any code that you have attempted so far to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
lst = [['^160magenta'], ['S159magenta', '//159magenta'], ['R158black', 'S158black', 'T158black'], ['S157black', 'T157yellow'], ['//156yellow']]
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        print(re.findall(r'\d+(.*)', j))
```

This results in

```
['magenta']
['magenta']
['magenta']
['black']
['black']
['black']
['black']
['yellow']
['yellow']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

pattern = "[a-z]+"
data = [
    ["^160magenta"],
    ["S159magenta", "//159magenta"],
    ["R158black", "S158black", "T158black"],
    ["S157black", "T157yellow"],
    ["//156yellow"],
]

sorted_data = list()
for row in data:
    new_row = list()
    for word in row:
        match = re.findall(pattern, word)
        new_row.extend(match)

    sorted_data.append(new_row)

print(sorted_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lst = [['^160magenta'], ['S159magenta', '//159magenta'], ['R158black', 'S158black', 'T158black'], ['S157black', 'T157yellow'], ['//156yellow']]
import re
lst=[[re.search('([a-z]{2,})',i).group(0) for i in j] for j in lst]
print(lst)
```

explaination:

> it searches for 2 or more alphabets and puts them in the list
> it also traverses original list using list comprehension twice
> a non list comprhension version would be:

```py
lst = [['^160magenta'], ['S159magenta', '//159magenta'], ['R158black', 'S158black', 'T158black'], ['S157black', 'T157yellow'], ['//156yellow']]
temp=[]
for j in lst:
  for i in j:
    temp.append(re.search('([a-z]{2,})',i).group(0))

print(temp)
```

Comment: @will.cass.wrig's answer will give you lists for each colour , desired output was a nested list, right? this should do it i guess

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @borchvm Thanks for your suggestion. Will keep that in mind. Although I don't know what I can explain , I mean the regex format or list comprehension. I have been told this on my second account as well . I just can't explain why it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely cleaner ways to solve this but this is one way

```
lst = [['^160magenta'], ['S159magenta', '//159magenta'], ['R158black', 'S158black', 'T158black'], ['S157black', 'T157yellow'], ['//156yellow']]
lst2 = []
alphabet = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
for i in lst:
    NewList = []
    for d in i:
        for p in range(len(d)):
            if d[p] not in  alphabet:
                d = d.replace(d[p]," ")
        d = d.replace(" ","")
        NewList.append(d)
    lst2.append(NewList)
print(lst2)
```

This results in

```
[['magenta'], ['magenta', 'magenta'], ['black', 'black', 'black'], ['black', 'yellow'], ['yellow']]
```